# Timestamp format iso with timezone and special format

Tags: python, datetime

I was trying some API e-commerce and i followed their example, but I keep getting Timestamp error / mismatch.

The API requires a timestamp in this format:

```
2017-08-29T09:54:00+07:00
```

I tried:

```
datetime.now().isoformat()
```

But it returns without the timezone:

```
'2017-08-29T09:54:57.702000'
```

then I tried:

```
datetime.now(pytz.timezone( 'Asia/Jakarta' )).isoformat()
```

but it returns:

```
2017-08-29T09:54:00.547000+07:00
```

Basically the python version doesn't use : for the minutes and seconds and it seems they also gives the microsecond which the API does not need. How do i get this format in python 2?

year-month-day then T hour-minute-second+Timezone

```
2017-08-29T09:54:00+07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
datetime.now(pytz.timezone( 'Asia/Jakarta')).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
```